# Is it possible to set default zoom or control Microsoft Edge built-in PDF Viewer from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, microsoft-edge

I'm working on an application which displays PDF in iframe. I'd like to open it as "Fit to width". In JavaScript I add `#view=FitH`:

```
<iframe id="previewFrame" frameborder="0" src="' + link + '#view=FitH"></iframe>
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Edge.

Is there a way how to set the default zoom in Edge's PDF Viewer?

Or control the Viewer from JavaScript, something like `pdfZoomInButton.click()`?

**Update:**

The actual link to the file looks like this

`https://myApp/Services.asmx/DownloadFile?id=someId#view=FitH`

On the server side there's quite complicated process but in the end the file  is loaded into a stream and then sent as response like this `stream.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);`

Comment: please provide a test environment to illustrate your problem, e.g. in codepen

Comment: My test result is the same as the answer below. `view=FitH` works in Edge. Which version of Edge are you using? Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? So that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: The thing is, the actual link to the file looks something like this `https://myApp/Services.asmx/DownloadFile?id=someId#view=FitH` and on the server side it's loaded into a stream and then sent as response like this `stream.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);`
I'm not sure how to make a snippet out of this, on the client side it's just the iframe I already posted.

Comment: I think that's due to different designs in different browsers, just like what KJ says. Edge's pdf viewer is different from Firefox's. I don't find other ways to change the PDF viewer and I think using the [parameters](https://pdfobject.com/pdf/pdf_open_parameters_acro8.pdf) is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

No problem, those directives are in url terms "fragments" thus must not be fragmented from their parent. The convention was introduced by Adobe for use with PDF plugins, so the whole string needs to be handled as one by the pdf viewer. All browsers use differently, Edge is better at respecting Adobe phrasing whereas Firefox use their own response to different phrasing. In all cases they are a sub set of Adobe's full repertoire. Plug-ins other than Acrobat may just respond to some or none, depending on how they are transferred.

[image]

## The inline Frame in Edge

```
<table><tr><td>in.pdf#view=Fit</td><td>in.pdf#view=FitH (=default)</td><td>in.pdf#view=FitV</td></tr><tr>
<td><iframe id="previewFrame" frameborder="0" src="in.pdf#view=Fit"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></td>
<td><iframe id="previewFrame" frameborder="0" src="in.pdf#view=FitH"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></td>
<td><iframe id="previewFrame" frameborder="0" src="in.pdf#view=FitV"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></td>
</tr></table>
<p>
<table><tr><td>in.pdf#view=FitB (ignored ?)</td><td>in.pdf#view=FitH,200 (works)</td><td>in.pdf#view=FitV,200 (N/A for portrait)</td></tr><tr>
<td><iframe id="previewFrame" frameborder="0" src="in.pdf#view=FitB"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></td>
<td><iframe id="previewFrame" frameborder="0" src="in.pdf#view=FitH,200"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></td>
<td><iframe id="previewFrame" frameborder="0" src="in.pdf#view=FitV,200"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe></td>
</tr></table>
```

***I see the opposite latest Firefox versions do not work with #AcrobatViewTags*** 1st example is native 2nd example is where tags do not get handed over.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess the issue in my case is, that the link is not a link to the file itself, but link to server, which then spits out the file as OutputStream. Other than that I don't see why shouldn't it be working.

I must admit I didn't try it with "plain pdf" file (which anyhow isn't an option for me). 
Based on the results my googling gave me I found it was not possible to control the PDF Viewer in Edge 2-3 years ago, couldn't find anything which would work for me, that's why I asked here. Interestingly enough, it works for me in firefox (both classic and developer edition).