# Filepond PDF Preview compatibility

Tags: filepond

I'm trying to display PDF in a filepond instance.
I'm working on `Vue2` with the following dependencies

```
"filepond": "^4.30.4",
"filepond-plugin-pdf-preview": "^1.0.4"
```

In a page component I setup the filepond as follows

```
<setup>
    ...

    // Import FilePond component 
    import vueFilePond, { setOptions } from "vue-filepond";
    // Import FilePond styles
    import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
    // Import FilePond plugins
    import "filepond-plugin-pdf-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-pdf-preview.css";

    // Create filepond 
    const FilePond = vueFilePond(FilePondPluginPdfPreview);
    setOptions({
         allowPdfPreview: true,
         pdfComponentExtraParams: 'toolbar=0&view=fit&page=1'
    });

    ...
</setup>
```

Also I want 3 PDF inlines so :

```
<style>
    .filepond--item {width: calc(33% - 0.5em);}
</style>
```

Now the problem I'm having is the following with Firefox and Internet Explorer : the `view=fit` doesn't work.

```
Firefox (don't see the bottom of the PDF)
```

[image: Firefox]

```
Microsoft Edge (I don't see much of the PDF)
```

[image: MicrosoftEdge]

And what I'd like is to have the exact same result as the one obtained in `Chrome`
[image: Chrome]

Is there a workaround ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser views are very much down to user settings

here are Edge variables and FireFox side by side and we can see there is no one fits both, so the best solution needs detect browser and use different settings accordingly.

**Chrome  uses #view=FitV&page=1

Firefox uses #zoom=FitV&page=1**

[image]

Note edge on the left is affected more by user settings as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72384838/10802527